# Fixing graph for predicted values multi-level logit regression in R

Tags: r, graph, regression, logistic-regression, multi-level

I'm using World Values Survey data to investigate the relationship between prejudice to immigrants (measured as whether someone mentions that they would not want an immigrant as a neighbour - binary 0/1) and town size (categorical), controlling for a range of other factors.

I have done a multi-level logistic regression with random intercepts by country.

```
twolevellogit <- glmer(V39 ~ as.factor(town_size) +as.factor(education) + as.factor(lower_class) + immigrant_parent  + age + female + (1 | V2), family = binomial("logit"), data = WVS6a)
```

I want to graph my results by showing the predicted values of the likelihood of someone from each town size responding that they are against living next to an immigrant (V39).

```
predprob <- fitted(twolevellogit)

predlogit <- logit(predprob, inverse = TRUE) 

datapred <- unique(data.frame(cbind(predlogit = predlogit, V2 = WVS6a$V2, town_size = WVS6a$town_size)))


xyplot(predlogit ~ town_size, data = datapred, groups = V2, type = c("l"), xlim= c(1, 8), ylim= c(0.45, 0.7))
```

My graph, however, looks like this. Very messy and confusing - as far as I'm aware it should look more like 42 parallel lines. I think perhaps it is a problem to do with missing data (there are many NAs within the data) however I cannot seem to solve it with any na.action commands.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tXsQ2J-jQwqlr4BFMYaIRZ3lermRNmvc/view?usp=sharing

I was wondering if anyone had any advise this would be amazing, additionally advise on how to make this graph using ggplot2 is very welcomed.

Comment: For the visualization, showing a large number of 'parallel' lines can be difficult in itself. It might be more informative to either split up the 42 lines in 2x2 subplots, or only to take a small sample of say 10 cities.  Also the lines might not be entirely parallel, as you have fixed effects in the model. Observations with identical fixed effects will be parallel, while none-identical will not be parallel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Oliver, I agree with you about plotting the graph within subsets of samples for clarity - at the moment this is a bit of a trial run. Do you mean that because countries will have different demographic in terms of the fixed effects in my model they will be predicted according to this?

Comment: I'm cooking up an answer to help out, once I've got a bit of time. Hopefuly it will help out.